# Saving/serialization dynamically changeable qml object to file, or string, or bytearray

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using my own qml components from separated .qml files to create dynamically changeable UI element and want to save it to another .qml file from application in order to load it in the future app session, but i can't find the way to do it other than manually generate .qml file from hierarchy of QQuickItem C++ objects. So, is there the light way to generate .qml file from qml engine or not?

Comment: I don't think there is any support for serializing a QML object tree and that you are going to have to roll your own.

Comment: I would store only the item type and all its properties, you can do all that from C++.